# Spring Boot @MockBeans - How to use the same beans in multiple test classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I have multiple security test classes where I am testing authorization to different REST endpoints, and I would like to mock the beans of all the repositories that ApplicationContext will spin up. I have the tests running and everything works correctly, but I'd like to not duplicate my @MockBeans in every security test class.

I've tried creating a configuration class and putting the MockBeans there, but I receive a 404 error.

The current test class is setup like this and it works, but I have to duplicate the @MockBeans() in each class:

```
@WebMvcTest(value = [ScriptController, SecurityConfiguration, ScriptPermissionEvaluator])
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension)
@MockBeans([@MockBean(ObjectRepository), @MockBean(ChannelRepository), 
@MockBean(ChannelSubscriberRepository)])
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ScriptControllerSecurityTest extends Specification
```

I'd like to setup a configuration class like this and use it inside of my test class with @ContextConfiguration(classes = MockRepositoryConfiguration) in the test class.

```
@Configuration
@MockBeans([@MockBean(ObjectRepository), @MockBean(ChannelRepository), 
@MockBean(ChannelSubscriberRepository)])
class MockRepositoryConfiguration
{}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the annotations to `Specification` itself?

Comment: @JoãoDias Specification in this class is coming from our spock dependency, so I don't think that is what I am looking for. https://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/Specification.html

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that. Have you tried a custom meta-annotation then?

Comment: @JoãoDias I have not - I'm not crazy familiar with Spring, so im not quite sure what the best solution is - if you have an idea of how that might work/be implemented I could try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a custom meta-annotation as follows:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.Type)
@MockBeans([@MockBean(ObjectRepository), @MockBean(ChannelRepository), 
@MockBean(ChannelSubscriberRepository)])
public @interface CustomMockBeans {
}
```

And then annotate your test class with it:

```java
@WebMvcTest(value = [ScriptController, SecurityConfiguration, ScriptPermissionEvaluator])
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension)
@CustomMockBeans
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ScriptControllerSecurityTest extends Specification
```

Comment: With some initial testing - this seems to be working! I'm curious what the difference in this is compared to using @ContextConfiguration? Is there some backend spring magic that is making the mocked beans behave differently when using this?

Comment: I guess that `@ContextConfiguration` is not scanned in a `@WebMvcTest` given that this will only create a partial Spring context. Maybe it only works with fully-fledged integration tests with `@SpringBootTest`. But this is just a guess.

Comment: That seems like a good guess. Either way I will take it. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Consider upvoting the answer and accept it as the answer so that your question can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it and easily understand which could be a possible solution for similar questions ;) Thanks!